# How can I use 'continue' and `break` in an extension method?

Tags: c#, .net, morelinq

I have defined the following extension method:

```
public static void ForEach<T>(this IEnumerable<T> sequence, Action<T> action)
{
   foreach (T obj in sequence)
   { 
      action(obj); 
   } 
}
```

I can then use it as:

```
new [] {1, 2, 3} // an IEnumerable<T>
.ForEach(n => 
{
  // do something 
});
```

I want to be able to take advantage of `continue` and `break` inside my extension method so that I can do:

```
new [] {1, 2, 3}
.ForEach(n => 
{
    // this is an overly simplified example
    // the n==1 can be any conditional statement
    // I know in this case I could have just used .Where
    if(n == 1) { continue; }
    if(n == -1) { break; }      
    // do something 
});
```

Can these keywords only be used within a `for`, `foreach`, `while` or `do-while` loops?

Comment: IMHO, this extension method makes no sense at all. It just complicates your code. Why not use the `foreach` loop?  You don't have to replace everything with an extension method.

Comment: @Daniel - I would have to disagree, I am a big fan of functional programming `linq` and `morelinq` and in my opinion (and the opinion of many others in my team) this is much easier to read than the alternative.

Comment: For each is already on list fyi

Comment: but not on IEnumerable ;-) hence why it is available in `MoreLinq`

Answer (score 7):

> Can these keywords only be used within a for, foreach, while loops?

Yes. Those statements are limited to loop types. [As the docs say](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/923ahwt1.aspx):

> The continue statement passes control to the next iteration of the
>   enclosing **while, do, for, or foreach** statement in which it appears.

[And](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/adbctzc4.aspx):

> The break statement terminates the **closest enclosing loop or switch
>   statement** in which it appears. Control is passed to the statement that
>   follows the terminated statement, if any.

I'd recommend you use a regular `foreach`, which is self expressive as is. I think any attempt to use them semantically inside your `ForEach` extension method will result in weirder code than using a regular loop.

I mean, is this not simpler?:

```
var arr = new [] {1, 2, 3}
foreach (int number in arr)
{
    if(n == 1) { continue; }      
    if(n == -1) { break; }      
}
```

Comment: tnx, I guess I should  have included in the question how one could implement jump logic in that extension method.

Comment: @MaYaN I added a remark to my answer. You can find a hack around this, but I guess you'll end up with uglier code. I'd use a regular foreach instead.

Comment: I think the use of this extension method should be considered in the context of a codebase where almost everything is functional and linq based. if you have functional methods everywhere then a `foreach` such as the above breaks the harmony :-) the `overly` simplified example in my question was just to get the ball rolling.

Comment: @MaYaN Why does it break "functionality"? Because it isn't LINQ based? LINQ can be of great help to readability, but on the other hand can make terribly unreadable code if used incorrectly. I wouldn't force "LINQ all the things" where it isn't really the place. That, and the fact that LINQ has some performance overhead.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to Yuval's answer I'd like to add that you *could* implement something like this as follows:

Change the `Action<T>` into a `Func<T, bool>` which takes a `T` parameter and returns a `bool` result.

The "continue" case could easily be handled by returning from the function upon the condition, thus continuing with the next iteration of the loop.

The "break" case could be handled by returning a `bool` from the function that indicates whether to continue or not:

```
public static void ForEach<T>(this IEnumerable<T> sequence, Func<T, bool> action)
{
  foreach (T obj in sequence)
  { 
    if (!action(obj)) 
      break;
  }
}

new [] {1, 2, 3}.ForEach(n => 
{
    if(n == 1) { return true;}      
    if(n == -1) { return false; }  

    // do something 
    ...
    return true;
});
```

Comment: You'll be wanting to use `Func<T, bool>` instead of `Action<T>` then since action returns void.

Comment: @TrevorPilley Of course. I was just going to edit, as I had to google how to return a value from an action first :-)

Comment: @TrevorPilley: While that is true, IMO it isn't a reason for a downvote.

Comment: @TrevorPilley I modified my answer. Thanks everybody.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar how do you have a 33.6k rep and not know `Func<T, bool>` without google?

Comment: I would change `TResult` to `bool`, since you can't do `!` on `object`.

Comment: @PatrickHofman: The answer is perfectly valid. This is the right way to emulate continue and break. The answer simply had a small syntax error :)

Comment: @TrevorPilley Well, you do some things more often than others. This is on the "I don't use it that often"-side in my case. Sometimes I do have to google stuff and I'm not ashamed :-D

Comment: AFAIK `ForEach` won't break when a `false` is returned. Did you mean to use `All`?

Comment: @Motti he wrote his own implementation.

Comment: I missed that, why write `ForEach` with the semantics of `All` rather than use `All`?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, those keyword are limited to `while`, `do`, `for`, and `foreach` (as Yuval referenced).

This code would resemble roughly the same as you ask:

```
bool shouldBreak = false;

new [] {1, 2, 3}
.ForEach(n => 
{
    if (!shouldBreak)
    {
        if(n == 1) { /* no action */ }      
        else if(n == -1) { shouldBreak = true; }
        else
        {
            // do something 
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: This will still loop over all the collection just not do anything after breaking. It breaks the whole laziness of `Linq`.

Comment: True. Don't use LINQ ;) A `for` would do better in this case.